# Prove compactness of closed disc in complex space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

As the title stated, I'm trying to prove that a closed disc P:={$ z: |z|\le R_0$} is compact, where z is a complex number

Is it okay to use Heine-Borel theorem here to assume $P\subset R^n$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that $P$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: Can I say that since P is contained in the ball of radius $R_0$ centered at origin, thus P is bounded? It seems trivial.

Comment: Yes. Basically a set $A$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in A$, we have $|x| \leq M$. Here you just take $M = R_0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** **|z|≤$R_0$** represents a closed disc of radius $R_0$ in complex plane containing all of its limit points.